# MSVS solution file generator?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm looking for a simple tool, that accepts a path, scans folders, and creates a solution (sln) file with all the projects found.

Setting project dependencies automatically would be a big plus for the tool from me.

I know it is simple to write the thing, but there must be plenty of "little helper tools" out there that can do the job for me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following search on google

```
 "visual studio" "solution file" generator
```

I came up with the following item:

```
 http://www.riaform.com/utility,solgen,utility.aspx
```

It has source code available too. I've never run it, so I can't speak to its accuracy or stability.  In any case the code should be useful as a starting point for building your own, should you need to.

Comment: Thx for reply. This is useful utility, but not what I'm looking for. It accepts root project and creates solution with all the child projects in it. Good, but not what I need. I have many project (~130) and there is no single "root" projects (there are 10-15 root projects). The code there might be useful example. I already coded the part that creates the solution file ... project dependencies is a next step.

Comment: I think it warrants pointing out that it does come with code meaning : *You can customize it focusing on only changing the behavior you find unsuitable*

Comment: The tool does part of what I need and there are no better answers ;) ... so I consider this to be a valid one.